# Python: How do i convert data in text file into a dictionary?

Tags: python

Python: How do i convert data in text file into a dictionary?
I have lines of data in my text file i.e.: name = score
How would i convert this information into a dictionary?
Title says it all. Please help me.

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
    list = []
    for line in file:
        list.append(line[1:-1].split(","))
```

My input format:

```
Kik = 4
Lolol = 3
Kiko = 8 
Darkling = 1 
Johnny = 10
```

Comment: Please always provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem and describe what you already tried.

Comment: Dictionaries use [Key, Value] pairs. You'll have create a dictionary and relate the users names to the scores using this format. There are plenty of resources that have this as an example.

Comment: I am guessing the filepath is the filename, but that doesnt work either

Comment: please, provide us the content of your file. Few lines are good enough

Comment: Kik = 4
Lolol = 3
Kiko = 8
Darkling = 1
Johnny = 10

Comment: Each name and corresponding score is on a separate line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have file

name1 = value1

name2 = value2

name3 = value3

name4 = value4

```
import re

d = {}

with open('data', 'r') as f:

    for line in f:

        line =   re.sub('\s', '', line)

        key, value = line.split('=')

        d[key] = value

for el in d.items():

    print(el)
```

('name1', 'value1')

('name4', 'value4')

('name2', 'value2')

('name3', 'value3')

Comment: with open('data', 'r') as f: ---------- Is 'data' my file name?

Comment: "re" is a module used for regex.

Comment: you must replace "data" with your real file name. Which we dont know, since you have not posted all the code.

Comment: with open(str(age) + ".txt" , "r") as file:

Comment: ('Addy', '5')
('Mike', '1')
('Kik', '4')
('Sting', '0')
('Johnson', '4')
('Dylan', '1')
('Darkling', '1') ah ok

Answer (score 0):

You just need to split and strip:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    scores_dct = {name.strip(): sco.strip() for line in f 
                  for name, sco in (line.split("="),)}
print(scores_dct)
'Kik': '4', 'Lolol': '3', 'Kiko': '8', 'Darkling': '1', 'Johnny': '10'}
```

Or using `dict` with `map`:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    scores_dct = dict(map(str.strip,line.split("=")) for line in f)
    print(scores_dct)
{'Kik': '4', 'Lolol': '3', 'Kiko': '8', 'Darkling': '1', 'Johnny': '10'}
```